# Confused for writing robots.txt file

Tags: google-search-console, robots.txt

I am getting DNS error from last few 5 days in my Google Webmaster Tools. That's the reason I would like to confirm my *robots.txt* file.

Is the below *robots.txt* file is correct or not?

```
User-agent: *
Allow: /

Sitemap: http://example.com/sitemap.xml
```

Please help me to solve this doubt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're getting a DNS error, it's not related to your *robots.txt* - it's related to your DNS settings. You can check for DNS errors with online tools like:  [DNS Health](http://dnscheck.pingdom.com/)

If you need additional help with that, I'd suggest making a screenshot of your DNS table settings from your DNS service provider and asking another question with that screenshot pasted in it (i.e., [example](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/49429/using-a-custom-domain-how-to-update-an-a-record/49431#49431)).

By the way, the accepted answer regarding your other [robots.txt](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/49816/what-is-the-correct-way-to-write-my-robots-txt-file/49818#49818) question is correct. I would stick with that for what you were asking about previously - *robots.txt* directives are not the cause of any DNS errors.

Comment: dan, here is the error http://dnscheck.pingdom.com/?domain=ansoftsys.com&timestamp=1372108107&view=1  What action i should pick up to solve this problem

Comment: You've got issues with your `nameservers`. I'd close out this question and add a screenshot like I suggested to another question. I'll try to help there later.

Comment: now i received a new type of error from google adsense `Issues: Site does not comply with Google policies`  . Now what you recommend me for this?  http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/50021/when-google-adsense-says-site-does-not-comply-with-google-policies

Answer (score 1):

To allow all:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow:
```

To disallow all:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

It's a bit confusing, and unintuitive I know. As a simple way of generating them I tend to use the [generator tool](http://www.mcanerin.com/EN/search-engine/robots-txt.asp).

Comment: Still confused, some people are teaching in this way http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/49897/is-this-a-correct-robots-txt-file and you are teaching in some other way. Which one is correct?

Comment: The issue is being confused because in the other questions, you're asking about `Googlebots` exclusively, which the `Allow` directive is suggested to be used by them (see my original answer on this). If you're not specifying `Googlebots` like in this question, then the "Disallow" directive is more widely used. Again, this is dependent on whether you're only allowing `Googlebots` or not.